# check elements all have the same value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a legacy Rails project that uses Ruby 1.8  , I have an array of float numbers. it can contain values like `my_array = [12.20, 10.0, 3.5]`. How can I check if my_array contains all zero values? e.g. `[0,0,0]` or `[0.0,0.0]`. I know I can loop through & check element one by one, but I just wonder is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are all `my_array` elements zero?

```
my_array.all?(&:zero?)
```

Note that it is impossible to check this without a loop, whether implicit or explicit. An implicit loop like the above just reads prettier, but it does exactly the same thing as "loop through & check element one by one".

Comment: I actually asked wrongly. For my current question, your answer is correct, I will post another question for my exact case which contains key and value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59047402/check-values-in-a-hash

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly how Amadan said it is if you want to go idiomatic. Use [Enum#all?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F)

If you want some ideas to hack around it:

```
# uniq
array.uniq == [0]
array.uniq == [0.0] 

# min and uniq
my_array.uniq.count == 1 && my_array.min.zero?
my_array.uniq.count == 1 && my_array.uniq.first.zero?

# min, max, zero
min = my_array.min
(min == my_array.max) && min.zero?

# construct ==
my_array == ([0] * my_array.count)
my_array == ([0.0] * my_array.count)
```

Comment: These all do at least two loops each (except the last one, but it constructs an extra array), which makes them slower than `.all?(&:zero?)`; it is also less readable; and the `min, max, zero` ones are wrong (Ruby does not support Python-style relational operator chaining). If they had any advantage I would upvote, but they don't.

Comment: Good point with relation chain, I'll edit. @Amadan like I said when I started the answer, your answer is the best approach. The purpose of my answer was to challenge the mind and present some other perspective over the problem not to offer a "fast" solution. This is O(n) all the way ...

Comment: @Amadan btw, the first one does one loop ;)

Comment: :D True. It also did not exist when I wrote the comment. You're right, for learning the language these are nice; but I really, really hope no-one will use any of these in production code. (As I said, I couldn't upvote, but I didn't downvote, either.)

Comment: Also, the `min, max, zero` problem is not resolved by parentheses. You resolve the parentheses, they give you a `Boolean`, and you're left testing if `true == 0` or `false == 0`, both of which result in `false`.