# Check values in a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a legacy Rails project that uses Ruby 1.8 .

I have an hash of key-value where value is a float number.

For example, `my_hash = ['foo'=>12.20, 'bar'=>10.0]`. How can I check if `my_hash` contains all zero values? e.g. `['foo'=>0, 'bar'=>0, 'whatever'=>0]` or `['foo'=>0.0, 'bar'=>0, 'whatever'=>0.0]`.

I know I can loop through & check element one by one, but I just wonder is there a more elegant way?

Comment: `my_hash.values` gives you an array; then, per your previous question: `my_hash.values.all?(&:zero?)`. Alternately, `my_hash.all? { |k, v| v.zero? }`.

Comment: Amadan will come and give you the same answer with `.values` on `my_hash`

Comment: Haha, nice one. Was pretty close... 10 seconds

Comment: `['foo'=>12.20, 'bar'=>10.0]` creates an array containing a hash. It's equivalent to `[{'foo'=>12.20, 'bar'=>10.0}]` whereas you probably want `{'foo'=>12.20, 'bar'=>10.0}`

Answer (score 0):

use below code if my_hash is:
`[{"foo"=>0.0, "bar"=>0, "whatever"=>0.0}]`

```
my_hash.first.values.all?{|item| item.zero?}
```

or if my_hash is array, just:

```
my_hash.all?{|item| item.zero?}
```

Comment: why call `first`?

Comment: i think your my_hash variable is:
```[{"foo"=>0.0, "bar"=>0, "whatever"=>0.0}]```

Answer (score 0):

Check all values in the hash are zero or not?

```
 2.2.3 :006 > h={"foo"=>0.0, "bar"=>0, "whatever"=>0.0}
      => {"foo"=>0.0, "bar"=>0, "whatever"=>0.0} 
 2.2.3 :007 > h.values.all?{|a| a.zero?}
      => true
```

If it is an array of hash then

```
2.2.3 :001 > h = ['foo'=>0.0, 'bar'=>0, 'whatever'=>0.0]
 => [{"foo"=>0.0, "bar"=>0, "whatever"=>0.0}] 
2.2.3 :004 > h[0].values.all?{|a| a.zero? }
 => true
```

OR

```
2.2.3 :014 > h
 => [{"foo"=>0.0, "bar"=>0, "whatever"=>0.0}] 
2.2.3 :015 > h.first.values.all?{|a| a.zero?}
 => true
```

Any element is zero

```
2.2.3 :009 > h={"foo"=>0.0, "bar"=>2, "whatever"=>1.1}
 => {"foo"=>0.0, "bar"=>2, "whatever"=>1.1} 
2.2.3 :010 > h.values.any?{|a| a.zero?}
 => true 
2.2.3 :011 > h={"foo"=>0.2, "bar"=>2, "whatever"=>1.1}
 => {"foo"=>0.2, "bar"=>2, "whatever"=>1.1} 
2.2.3 :012 > h.values.any?{|a| a.zero?}
 => false
```